# Reed and Simon definition of product of distributions

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, microlocal-analysis

Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the space of $C^{\infty}$, compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and let $\mathcal{D}'$ denote its dual (i.e. the space of distributions). In volume II of Reed and Simon's *Methods of Mathematical Physics*, the authors introduce the following definition of the product of distributions (pg. 91), which I have reproduced below modulo some minor notational changes.

> **Definition.** Let $T,S\in\mathcal{D}'$. We say that $W\in\mathcal{D}'$ is the *product* of $T$ and $S$ if and only if for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, there exists some $f\in \mathcal{D}$, with $f\equiv 1$ near $x$ so that for each $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$,
>   $$\mathcal{F}(f^{2}W)(\xi) = (2\pi)^{-d/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\mathcal{F}(fT)(\eta) \mathcal{F}(f S)(\xi-\eta)d\eta, \tag{*}$$
>   where the integral in the RHS is absolutely convergent. If such a $W$ exists, we say the *product of $T$ and $S$ exists*.

Above, $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform on the space of tempered distributions.

The authors go on to claim in Theorem IX.43 that the product is well-defined and that there is at most one $W$ satisfying the definition. I am having trouble seeing that the uniqueness of the product. Looking at Reed and Simon's sketch of the proof, they claim without proof that if $W$ is a product for $T$ and $S$, then for any $g\in\mathcal{D}$,

$$\mathcal{F}(gf^{2}W) = (2\pi)^{-d/2}\mathcal{F}(gf T) \ast \mathcal{F}(f S) = (2\pi)^{-n/2} \mathcal{F}(f T)\ast \mathcal{F}(fg S), \tag{**}$$

citing associativity, which is valid because of the absolute convergence of the integral in the RHS of (*).

I do not see why absolute convergence of the integral alone is sufficient to warrant the change of variables needed to prove (**). It seems like one also needs some condition of the form
$$\xi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|\mathcal{F}(fT)(\eta)| |\mathcal{F}(fS)(\xi-\eta)|d\eta$$
is polynomially bounded, but this condition isn't assumed, nor do I see why it follows from (*). Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: A Fourier Transform of a distribution with compact support is an element of $\mathcal{O}_M$, the space of multipliers in $\mathcal{S}$, so it is polynomial bounded?!